# Python 3.12 - where is the Run menu?

Tags: python, python-idle

I am trying to follow a tutorial but the tutorial was made in an earlier version of Python.  I installed 3.12 and I have no Run menu option in the IDLE app.  The F5 key just emits a sounds when I click on it.  I'm searching all the documentation for any way to execute code that is saved in a file.  Any help would be appreciated.

I also tried using the Debug/Debugger option but that gives a screen with all buttons greyed out so I can only open and close the window.

Comment: And you must press command and f5 together in order for this to work.

Comment: @5rod F5 works by itself, including on macOS.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that. Thanks for the helpful knowledge, @Terry Jan Reedy.

Answer (score 1):

The comment has the answer for the Run menu: edit a file.

The debugger is not active until you run some code.  Just run, for instance, `print()` either in Shell or from the editor.